# Are there nonisotrivial elliptic curves over $\mathbb{G}_m$?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, elliptic-curves

Is there an elliptic curve over $\mathbb{C}[t, t^{-1}]$ that has a nonconstant $j$-invariant? What is an equation for such a curve, if it exists?

Comment: I'm probably going to write a short paper inspired this question (extending it to much more general families, i.e. Abelian schemes/geometric variations of Hodge structure).  I'd like to acknowledge you by name; please email me if that's OK.  My email is in my MO user page.

Comment: @DanielLitt: Sounds great, I'll take a look at it once it's done. Don't worry, no acknowledgement for me is necessary.

Comment: There's a draft of the paper ready--I've cited this question, of course.  Let me know if you'd like to take a look before I put it on the ArXiV.

Comment: @DanielLitt: Sorry for a late reply. Thanks for mentioning your paper, I've seen it on the arXiv

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Let me give an analytic argument, to complement Noam's algebraic one.  Suppose $E\to \mathbb{C}^*$ is an elliptic curve.  Then pulling back $E$ along the universal covering map (also known as the exponential map) $\mathbb{C}\to \mathbb{C}^*$, one obtains an elliptic curve $\tilde E\to \mathbb{C}$.  Choosing a basis for the first homology of $\tilde E$ induces a holomorphic map $$\mathbb{C}\to \mathbb{H},$$ where $\mathbb{H}$ is the upper half-plane, viewed as the moduli space of elliptic curves with a homology basis for $H_1$.  But any such map must be constant by Liouville's theorem.  $\blacksquare$

**Added Later.**  Since the OP enjoyed the sketch algebraic version in the comments (corrected by user74230), let me give some more details (and in particular, say what happens in characteristic $p>3$).  WLOG $k$ is algebraically closed.  Suppose $E\to \mathbb{G}_m/k$ is an elliptic curve.  If we can find some $n$ so that the pullback of $E$ along $\mathbb{G}_m\overset{[n]}\longrightarrow \mathbb{G}_m$ has trivial $\ell$-torsion, with $(\ell, p)=1$ and $\ell \gg 0$, we're done, because choosing a trivialization we get a map from $\mathbb{G}_m$ to a high genus modular curve, which must be constant as $\mathbb{G}_m$ is rational.

To do this, we must show that for infinitely many $\ell$, the map $E[\ell]\to \mathbb{G}_m$ has tame ramification at $0, \infty$.  It suffices to find $\ell$ so that $GL_2(\mathbb{Z}/\ell\mathbb{Z})$ has order prime to $p$.  But this order is $(\ell^2-1)(\ell^2-\ell)=\ell(\ell-1)^2(\ell+1).$  But by Dirichlet's theorem on primes in arithmetic progressions, there are infinitely many $\ell$ so that $\ell(\ell-1)^2(\ell+1)$ is prime to $p$, if $p>3$. $\blacksquare$

As Noam observes in the comment, the result is *false* in characteristic $2$ and $3$; he gives examples of non-isotrivial families in these characteristics.

Comment: One can make an algebraic version of this argument as follows, which works in arbitrary characteristic.  Some finite etale cover of $\mathbb{G}_m$ trivializes the $\ell$-torsion of $E$, and so after picking a trivialization induces a map from $\mathbb{G}_m$ to a modular curve.  But the genus of modular curves tends to infinity, so for large $\ell$, such a map must be constant.

Comment: This algebraic argument might have problems in characteristics 2 and 3.  The covering map $\ell:E \rightarrow E$ over $\mathbf{G}_m$ is generally not a Galois covering, just finite etale, corresponding to a representation of $\pi_1(\mathbf{G}_m)$ into ${\rm{GL}}_2(\mathbf{F}_{\ell})$ that might be wildly ramified at $0$ and $\infty$ in those low positive characteristics, so the corresponding cover (which depends on $\ell$) might not be a genus-0 curve.

Comment: Indeed $y^2 = x^3 + x^2 - t$ has discriminant $t$ and $j$-invariant $1/t$ in characteristic $3$.  Likewise $y^2 + xy = x^3 + t$ in characteristic $2$.

Comment: You're right of course; forgot about those other pesky covers.

Comment: @DanielLitt: Thank you. Of the four given proofs, I like the one that you give in your comment most, so I am going to accept this answer.

Comment: @DanielLitt: I'm confused a bit about some steps in your "algebraic" construction. Firstly, why if we manage to find such "big" enough $\ell$ with $(\ell,p)=1$ such that the pullback of $E/ \mathbb{G}_m$ along the multiplication map $[n]$ on the base has only trivial $\ell$ -torsion, then it's "trivialization" induces a map from base $\mathbb{G}_m$ to certain modular curve? Sidenote: what do you mean in this context by "trivialization"?

Comment: Also, I'm not sure what you mean by that in order to reach the above condition, we must show that for infinitely many $\ell$ the map $E[\ell] \to \mathbb{G}_m$ has tame ramification in $0, \infty$. But there  two points not live in the base $\mathbb{G}_m$. Do you ,maybe somehow consider there an extension to base $\mathbb{P}^1$?

Comment: @user267839 Regarding your first question, this uses the moduli description of modular curves--a map from $X$ to a modular curve is the same as a family of elliptic curves over $X$ with a suitable trivialization of their torsion, essentially by definition. For your second question, the fundamental group of $\mathbb{G}_m$ has inertia subgroups corresponding to the punctures $0, \infty$.

Comment: alright, so regarding my first question the claim is that one can find a $n$ such the pullback $E'$ of $E/ \mathbb{G}_m$ along covering $\mathbb{G}_m\overset{[n]}\longrightarrow \mathbb{G}_m$  has "trivial $\ell$- torstion" in the sense that there exist an iso between $E'[\ell]$ and constant grp scheme $((\mathbb{Z}/ \ell)^2)_{\mathbb{G}_m}$? That's the issue with trivialization, right? ... and based on this we obtain the map from $\mathbb{G}_m$ to the modular curve.

Comment: about the second point I'm not pretty sure if I understand exactly your argument in this context about reasoning about "ramification behavior" at $0, \infty$ of the map $E[\ell] \to \mathbb{G}_m$. You gave the argument that this comes from certain inertia groups of the fundamental group which "detect" them as a kind of - let me say "missing" points. Do I understand the picture correctly that one should think of this as "reasoning about ramification behavior in [naive](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unramified_morphism) sense of associated maps between the associated unique smooth

Comment: projective models, ie in case of $\mathbb{G}_m$ the projective line $\mathbb{P}^1$. So, when you say above that  " the map $E[\ell]\to \mathbb{G}_m$ has tame ramification in $\infty, 0$", do you tacitly refer to the "extended" map between assoc smooth projective models & their points? Or do I missing your concern?

Comment: #UPDATE: The two points I asked before are clear so far, so my last three comments can be ignored. But could you maybe loose few words on why $[n]$ becomes a trivializing cover for $\ell$ torsion in the sense you explained, when $E[\ell] \to \mathbb{G}_m$ is tamely ramified in "places" $0,\infty$ in above sense?

Comment: @user267839: The key fact here is that *any* tame cover of $\mathbb{G}_m$ is in fact isomorphic to a disjoint union of  $[n_i]$ for some $n_i$ (this follows e.g.~Grothendieck's theorem that specialization maps are surjective for tame fundamental groups). Now the scheme of trivializations of the $\ell$-torsion is étale over $\mathbb{G}_m$, so if you check it is tame you win.

Comment: What do you mean by the "scheme of trivializations" of the $\ell$-torsion precisely?

Comment: @user267839: The scheme $\text{Isom}_{\mathbb{G}_m}(E[\ell], (\mathbb{Z}/\ell\mathbb{Z})^2)$.

Comment: Why is this scheme of triv's of the $\ell$- torsion etale over $\mathbb{G}_m$? Is this a *feature* of torsion of elliptic curves, or does it hold in greater generality? Eg somethng like: Let $G/S$ finite etale group scheme over base $S$ such that every fiber $G_s$ is isomorphic to a finite constnt scheme $C/ \kappa(s)$, then $\text{Isom}_{S}(G, C_S)$ is *etale* over $S$ ( where $C_S$ sameconst finite gp scheme over $S$)? Or does it even hold more generally if we instead $C_S$ consider another finite etale $S$-gp scheme $H/S$ with $G_s \cong H_s$ that  $\text{Isom}_{S}(G, H)$ is etale over $S$?

Answer (score 18):

There is no such curve.

One way to see this is via the action of
${\rm Gal}\bigl(\overline{{\mathbb C}(t)}\big/{\mathbb C}(t)\bigr)$
on the group $E[p]$ of $p$-torsion points of a putative elliptic curve
$E / {\mathbb C}(t)$ that has good reduction at all $t \neq 0, \infty$.
The image of Galois would be abelian, because the coordinates of $E[p]$
would generate an extension of ${\mathbb C}(t)$ unramified above all
$t \in {\mathbb C}^*$, and ${\mathbb C}^*$ has abelian fundamental group.
On the other hand, once $p$ exceeds the order of a pole of the $j$-invariant
$j_E^{\phantom.}$, the image of Galois includes
a $p$-cycle ramified above that pole.  A $p$-cycle in 
${\rm SL}_2({\mathbb Z}/p{\mathbb Z})$ generates its own centralizer,
so the image of Galois would be a $p$-element subgroup of
${\rm SL}_2({\mathbb Z}/p{\mathbb Z})$.  It would follow that
$E$ has $p$ nontrivial $p$-torsion points rational over ${\mathbb C}(t)$
(because a $p$-cycle in ${\rm SL}_2({\mathbb Z}/p{\mathbb Z})$ fixes
a 1-dimensional space of $({\mathbb Z}/p{\mathbb Z})^2)$.
But this cannot happen for infinitely many $p$, **QED**.

The result can also be obtained by tracking down the cases when
Szpiro's inequality is sharp: 
a nonconstant elliptic curve over $E / {\mathbb C}(t)$
has discriminant degree at least $12$, and therefore conductor degree 
at least $\frac{12}{6} + 2 = 4$  by Szpiro; equality can hold in several ways, 
but in each case $j_E^{\phantom.}$ turns out to be constant.
(With good reduction away from $t=0$ and $t=\infty$,
the conductor degree is at most $2+2=4$.)

Comment: There might not be an entirely simple proof of this result. The nonconstant elliptic curves over ${\mathbb C}^*$ are quadratic twists
$y^2 = x^3 + at x^2 + bt^2 x + ct^3$, cubic twists
$y^2 = x^3 + at^2$ and $y^2 = x^3 + at^4$,
quartic twists $y^2 = x^3 + at x$ and $y^2 = x^3 + at^3 x$, and
sextic twists $y^2 = x^3 + at$ and $y^2 = x^3 + at^5$; any argument
must account for all of these.  The proof I gave is conceptual but
advanced; the Szpiro path is elementary (Szpiro is basically 
Mason = polynomial ABC) but requires case analysis.

Comment: Thank you. Why does the image of Galois induce a $p$-cycle ramified above the pole of $j_E$ (and what does that mean)?

Answer (score 6):

It is an older topic, and very nice answers have been given. But I am new in MO and let me give another answer.

The reason for nonexistence of such an elliptic curve is the same as for nonexistence of such an elliptic curve over $S:=$Spec$(\mathbb{C}[t])$. In order to have a universal elliptic curve one must remove the points from $S$ which correspond to elliptic curves with automorphism group larger than $\{ \pm1\}$, and these fibers have $j$-invariants 0 and 1728. This is explained in the book Arithmetic Moduli of Elliptic Curves by Katz and Mazur. So we must remove at least two points from $S$, i.e. inverting $t$ in $\mathbb{C}[t]$ is not enough.

This argument works if we replace $\mathbb{C}$ by any algebraically closed field of characteristic $p \geq 5$. But for $p=2$ or 3 we have $0 = 1728$, so it is enough to remove only one point from $S$ in these cases and this explains the existence of examples given by Elkies above.