# Discriminant locus of elliptic K3 surfaces

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, k3-surfaces, elliptic-surfaces

Given a complex elliptic K3 surface $\pi\colon X\rightarrow \mathbb P^1$, its *discriminant locus* is the divisor $$D = \sum_{i = 1}^s n_i P_i$$ on $\mathbb P^1$ such that $n_i$ is equal to the Euler-Poincaré characteristic of the fiber $\pi^{-1}(P_i)$, where the sum runs over the points $P_i \in \mathbb P^1$ such that $\pi^{-1}(P_i)$ is singular. It is well known that $\deg D = 24$.

> Conversely, given an effective divisor $D$ of degree $24$ on $\mathbb P^1$, when is it the discriminant locus of a complex elliptic K3 surface?

I am particularly curious about the minimal possible $s$. The maximal Euler-Poincaré characteristic of a singular fiber is $20$, so $s \geq 2$. But in case, say, $n_1 = 20$, then the fibration is of type $I_{14}^*,I_1,I_1,I_1,I_1$ (see [Schütt-Schweizer](https://arxiv.org/abs/0712.3873)), so indeed $s = 5$. Are smaller $s$ possible?

Comment: Since the moduli space of polarized K3 surfaces is hyperbolic, the inequality $s\geq 3$ holds. An example of an elliptic fibration with $s=3$ is provided by the Legendre elliptic curve $y^2= x(x-1)(x-\lambda)$ over $\mathbb{C}-\{0,1\}$. The total space of this fibration is not K3 though.

Comment: Sorry, I actually miswrote something in my comment. I meant to say that the moduli "space" of *elliptic curves* is hyperbolic. (Although the moduli space of polarized K3 surfaces is hyperbolic as well, it is the moduli space of elliptic curves which plays a role here.) Indeed, if $D$ is the support of the discriminant divisor of the elliptic surface $f:X\to \mathbb{P}^1$, then there is a non-constant morphism $\mathbb{P}^1 \setminus D \to \mathcal{M}$ induced by the Jacobian of $X\setminus f^{-1}D\to \mathbb{P}^1\setminus D$, where $\mathcal{M}$ is the moduli of elliptic curves.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The minimal $s$ is $3$.

It is attained by several elliptic K3's,
including $y^2 = x^3 + (t^2-t)^4$ which has IV* fibers at
$t = 0, 1, \infty$ and no other singular fibers. 
The comment by **Ariyan Javanpeykar** gives one argument that 
$s$ can be no smaller. (*See postscript.*
This uses characteristic zero; in small positive characteristic
$s$ can be as small as $1$, e.g. in characteristic 2 the elliptic K3 surface
$y^2 + y = x^3 + t^9$ has only one reducible fiber, at $t = \infty$.)

P.S. There are other ways to prove $s>2$; for example it follows from
Szpiro's inequality, which has an elementary proof via the 
Mason-Stothers theorem (polynomial ABC).  See MO 190530,
[Are there nonisotrivial elliptic curves over $\mathbb{G}_m$?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/190530), for this and
some related ideas.  (That question is related because
${\bf G}_m({\bf C}) = {\bf CP}^1 - \{0, \infty\}$ and
if an elliptic surface $\pi: X \to {\bf P}^1$ has $s \leq 2$
then one can choose the coordinate on ${\bf P}^1$ so that
each bad fiber maps to $0$ or $\infty$.)

Comment: Another "easy" way of showing that $s>2$ is to use that the modular curve $Y(n)$ is of genus at least two when $n>>0$. Indeed, suppose that $s\leq 2$ for $X\to \mathbb{P}^1$. Now, choose $n >0$ such that $X(n)$ has genus at least two. Note that adding level $n$ structure induces a new family $X'\to \mathbb{P}^1$ (because $s<3$), and thus a morphism $\mathbb{P}^1\to X(n)$.

Comment: Yes, that kind of argument was given in both Daniel Litt's answer to MO 190530 and in mine.  (It's related to your "hyperbolic" idea: ${\bf G}_m$ is not hyperbolic, so neither are its unramified covers.)

Comment: Yes, that's right. The argument actually goes back to Shafarevich (as you certainly know), and should appear somewhere in Barry Mazur's paper "Arithmetic on Curves" (https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.bams/1183553167).

Comment: @NoamD.Elkies Hi Noam, how do you verify that the singular fibers of $y^2 = x^3 + (t^2-t)^4$ are IV* at $t=0,1, \infty$ and that this fibration has no other singular fibers?

Comment: @AmorFati In general the singular fibers are the values of $t$ where
the discriminant $\Delta$ vanishes.
Here $\Delta$ is a multiple of $(t^2-t)^8$
[really $(t_1 t_0 (t_1-t_0))^8$ where $(t_1:t_0)$ are projective coordinates,
so the $t_0=0$ point "$\infty$" is also a zero of $\Delta$;
clearly the only others are $t_1=0$ and $t_1=t_0$, i.e. $t=0$ and $t=1$].
The reduction type can be determined by Tate's algorithm.
Since we are not in characteristic 2 or 3 here, we can recognize
Type IV* from the valuations $v(c_4) \geq 3$, $v(c_6) = 4$.

Comment: @NoamD.Elkies I agree that $v(c_6)=4$, but I do not see how $v(c_4)$ is not zero: $v(c_4)$ measures the order of vanishing of the coefficient in the $x$-term, $y^2 = x^3 + (t^2-t)^4$ has no $x$-term...

Comment: The curve is $y^2 = x^3 + (-c_4/48) x + (-c_6/864)$, 
so $c_4$ is the $x$-coefficient and $c_6$ is the constant coefficient.
For us $c_4=0$, which has valuation $+\infty$, so $v(c_4) \geq 3$ holds.
The quadruple root of $c_6$ gives $v(c_6) = 4$.